# (Why) does accessing outerHeight cancel click/mouseup/focus event?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I've encountered a weird issue - accessing any DOM element's `outerHeight`, or simply logging that element to browser's console in a blur event seems to cancel the click event that caused the blur - when some special criteria is met.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. There are 2 inputs, first is initially visible, the other hidden
2. When the first input receives focus, the 2nd input will be shown
3. When the 2nd input receives focus, it remains shown
4. When both inputs lose focus, and none of them are focused, the 2nd input will be hidden

However, it seems that when I simply try to do something like `$('body')[0].outerHeight` in my blur event handler, the second input never receives the click or focus. Since it's too much to simply write down, here's a link to JSFiddle that demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7K2Ha/3/

Note - it happens the same with plain JS

Can anybody explain why this happens and are there ways around this?

Comment: The third one seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you bind focus/blur events to **all** .jq inputs. And then you add next event handlers (which means, that all of them will be executed - including the first one, which removes the `has-focus` class).

Check this fiddle, line 20: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/michasko/7K2Ha/5/).

```
$('#input3').unbind('blur').on('blur', //...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not specific to `offsetHeight`, and I believe if you comment out that line you don't get the effect simply because the browser will not call an empty function block for performance/optimizer reasons.

It seems to come down to the execution order of the events (especially problematic when more than one jquery event of the same type is wired up).
Check out what happens when you wire up the blur/mouseover/etc. events that all `$('input.jq')` elements have in common at the very end: http://jsfiddle.net/7K2Ha/6/

All I did was move the topmost javascript block to the bottom, and suddenly it works. In that case, the `focus` event seems to occur before the `blur` event. Notice how before the `focus` would never be called.

As a more robust solution, I'd only work with one event that covers both:

```
$('input.jq')
.on('focus', function() {
    // get focus'ed elements parent
    var thisParent = $(this).parent('div')
    thisParent.addClass('has-focus');

    // get all other parents 
    var otherParents = $('input.jq').parent('div').not(thisParent);
    otherParents.removeClass('has-focus');
})
```

See [updated JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7K2Ha/8/).